# Why does Assimp appear to be loading vertices in the incorrect order in this code?

Tags: opengl, c++, blender, assimp

I'm getting a weird bug in my code that is reading in the vertices from an `.obj` file.

The `.obj` file is just a cube, hence there are eight vertices. When I print out the vector it seems to work perfectly up until the 5th vertex, and then it seems to read the last 3 backwards.

This is the file:

```
# Blender v2.69 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib cube.mtl
o Cube
v 2.000000 -2.000000 -2.000000
v 3.000000 -3.000000 3.000000
v -4.000000 -4.000000 4.000000
v -5.000000 -5.000000 -5.000000
v 6.000000 6.000000 -6.000000
v 7.999999 7.000000 7.000001
v -8.000000 8.000000 8.000000
v -9.000000 9.000000 -9.000000
usemtl Material
s off
f 1 2 3 4
f 5 8 7 6
f 1 5 6 2
f 2 6 7 3
f 3 7 8 4
f 5 1 4 8
```

This is my code:

```
m->vertices = new glm::vec3[m->numVertices];
for (GLuint i = 0 ; i < m->numVertices ; i++) {
    const aiVector3D* pPos = &(mesh->mVertices[i]);
    m->vertices[i] = glm::vec3 (pPos->x, pPos->y, pPos->z);
    std::cout << "X:" << m->vertices[i].operator[](0) << " Y:" << m->vertices[i].operator[](1) << " Z:" << m->vertices[i].operator[](2) << std::endl;   
}
```

However this is what is stored in the vector (what the above code prints out):

```
X:2 Y:-2 Z:-2
X:3 Y:-3 Z:3
X:-4 Y:-4 Z:4
X:-5 Y:-5 Z:-5
X:6 Y:6 Z:-6
X:-9 Y:9 Z:-9
X:-8 Y:8 Z:8
X:8 Y:7 Z:7
```

As you can see the last three lines are messed up, I have no idea how this is happening in the loop.

Comment: Though not entirely sure, I assume assimp had to duplicate some vertices due to triangulation (the file has quads and not triangles) so in order to calculate the normals correctly.

Comment: The bug is not in the code you've shown us. Whatever is populating `mesh->mVertices` is most likely at fault. As concept3d pointed out, your file is stored in quads (you can tell with the bottom part defining 4 indices per object). It could easily be undefined input to a system that only knows how to read triangles.

Comment: Thanks to Concept3d and Byte56 for pointing it out. I found out that the problem with the mesh was actually with how I was loading my indices and not a problem with the vertices. I just assumed there was a problem with with the vertices as they seemed to not be loading properly. Apologies, it's my first time diving into OpenGL and Assimp. Thanks for the help guys

Comment: @Rhakiras, what was the problem? I thought ASSIMP packs the indices into an array and we simply iterate from 0 to numIndecies - 1 ?